# Postgres - most efficient way of storing a small number

Tags: postgresql, performance

I need to add new field to a table. The field will only store a number that ranges from 0 to maybe 30, so (in theory) a single byte field should be fine.

The smallest integer data-type listed in the documentation is SMALLINT which requires 2 bytes.

The table I want to add the field to is partitioned and currently holds approximately 3 billion rows. So adding a 2 byte field to each row should require 6 billion bytes, or 6 GB.

For reasons I still haven't fathomed, (see this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/322025)) I'm running out of space when adding a SMALLINT field to a large table.

QUESTION - is there a single-byte datatype I can use to store a number with only a very small range of values?

Comment: Looking at your linked question, it’s unlikely you’ll benefit from reducing the size of the column - the simple act of adding a column means a full rebuild of the table (indexes and all) so that’s going to be the majority of your space requirement. Upgrading your version should give you a better code path here so you won’t require so much spare space

Comment: Note that Postgres 10 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible. (And as mentioned in the other question: with a supported version it's highly likely you wouldn't have run in this issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use the [special "char"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-SPECIAL-TABLE) type (note the double quotes and no length), then cast your values on input and output.

Tell us though, what percentage of the total table size are the 3 GB you wish to save, and why is it important enough to warrant the extra effort?

Comment: please see linked question. Nearly 900GB freespace is NOT enough to add a 4 byte SMALLINT field to the table.

Comment: Well, there's now an answer to _that_ question that tells you why you're running out of space (and it's not because of 6 GB).